The differences between "estate, complex, and development" as nouns
Scale: An estate often refers to a large piece of land, while a complex is typically a smaller, self-contained group of buildings. A development is broader, referring to the process or result of creating new real estate projects.
Purpose: Estates can have historical or residential connotations, complexes are functional and specific, and developments emphasize construction and planning.
Location: Estates are often rural or suburban, while developments and complexes are more common in urban or suburban areas.
This is what I saw online about the differences between these three terms. Are they also what you imagine when you hear these words? I especially doubt the development-related part, as it differs from what I found in the Oxford Dictionary:

development: a piece of land with new buildings on it
 complex: a group of buildings of a similar type together in one place
 estate: an area of land with a lot of houses or factories of the same type on it


Note that estate, in particular, has different meanings in different parts of the English-speaking world. The Oxford definition you quote is the British usage and it can very easily be urban. It is the American usage that tends to be more rural and apply to a large tract of land.

Development has multiple meanings: you seem to be confusing the abstract meaning "the act, process, or result of developing" with the non-abstract meaning of a piece of land that has been developed. You can't just assume that a word only has one meaning: all these terms have multiple meanings (even just in the area of real estate), and unpicking all the different meanings is too much for a short answer.

Note that 'development' says 'new buildings'. I (UK) would call a housing estate a development only if it was fairly recently built on land that had previously had another use. I agree that 'complex' implies a group of buildings linked together or belonging to one company.
